# AWS Elastic Beanstalk skipping db:migrate, getting wrong value for RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using Ruby 2.7 on Elastic Beanstalk, [as described here in AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/relnotes/release-2021-10-2-linux.html#release-2021-10-21-linux.platforms.ruby).  I'm running Rails 6.1.4.1.  Rake is 13.0.6.

Whether or not Beanstalk executes `db:migrate` is supposed to depend on the value of `RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS`, which defaults to false.  I have made double-sure it is true by including it in my `.ebextensions` setup, which I see executing:

```
commands:
  01_install_yarn:
    command: npm install yarn -g
  02_symlink_yarn:
    command: ln -s -f "$(npm bin --global)"/yarn /usr/bin/yarn
  03_install_dependencies:
    command: yum install postgresql-devel
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment: 
    RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS: false
```

In fact, I know for sure the value is **false**, because I can see it on the Beanstalk instance when I connect to it.

If you ssh to the host and run `sudo cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env`, you see a dump of the environment -- all those config params, as well as injected RDS variables.  Very handy for debugging:

```
$ sudo cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env
PATH=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/shims:/opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
RACK_ENV=production
RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS=false
RAILS_SKIP_ASSET_COMPILATION=false
BUNDLE_WITHOUT=test:development
(etc)
```

However, `/var/log/eb-engine.log` consistently skips migrations and shows this:

```
2021/11/11 23:17:52.261630 [INFO] Running command /bin/su webapp -c bundle exec /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/checkforraketask.rb db:migrate
2021/11/11 23:17:57.083890 [INFO] Found db:migrate task in Rakefile
2021/11/11 23:17:57.083955 [INFO] Skipping db:migrate task (RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS=true).
2021/11/11 23:17:57.083968 [INFO] Executing instruction: configure log streaming
```

It is showing true instead of false!  And I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

I may sidestep this with a `container_command` to force the task to execute, but I really want to know what's up.  Is this a bug in Beanstalk?  I can't seem to trace it any further; `checkforraketask` just looks like this:

```
require 'rake'

Dir.chdir '/var/app/staging'

Rake.application.init
Rake.application.load_rakefile

tasks = Rake.application.tasks.collect(&:name)
exit 0 if tasks.include? ARGV[0]
exit 1
```

And `Rakefile` like this:

```
require_relative "config/application"

Rails.application.load_tasks
```

There are no tasks in `lib/tasks`, so I assume this output comes from that last line?  I'm stuck.  How do I get Beanstalk to recognize the correct value and run the migration?

Answer (score 1):

I too would love to know the answer to this question.

As a workaround I created the following ebextension to solve the problem:

.ebextensions/03_rake-db-migrate.config

```
container_commands:
  rake_db_migrate:
    command: "RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate"
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30870294)

Answer (score 0):

Are you skipping asset compilation (RAILS_SKIP_ASSET_COMPILATION=true)?

In my case, when is true, the migrations are skipping too.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was setting `RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS=false` using the Elastic Beanstalk "Environment properties" (under Configuration). Although it wasn't getting picked up either.

I used this command which fetches all the environment variables directly, and sets them (earlier than EB does by default), and now it respects that environment variable by default:

```
export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)
```

To have this run at the right time, put it in a file like this:
`.platform/hooks/prebuild/09_fetch_env_vars_early.sh`, with a bash shebang at the top of the file like this: `#!/bin/bash`.

To verify it worked, look in `/var/log/eb-engine.log`, and it should appear like this:

```
[INFO] Found db:migrate task in Rakefile
[INFO] Running command /bin/su webapp -c bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

You can see `eb-engine.log` by using the `eb logs` command, or by `eb ssh`'ing to the server after deploy.